# How to introduce non-core dependencies to js libraries via *.libraries.yml in drupal 8?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, namespaces, yaml, drupal-8

I am working on a Drupal 8 template that makes use of a good number of bootstrap plugins on a number of pages. How can I add the non-core Bootstrap library to the dependencies of such plugins in the THEME.libraries.yml file? I don't need the bootstrap framework on all pages - just those with certain plugins included.

Here is a sample code from my *.libraries.yml yet the last line doesn't work.

```
bootstrap-datepaginator:
  js:
    assets/global/plugins/.js: {}
  css:
    theme:
      assets/global/plugins/.css: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - THEME_NAME/js/bootstrap
```

Comment: js and css file names of the sample are intentionally deleted. I just don't know how to address the non-core bootstrap library under dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my problem; you just need to add the registered name of the library after the theme_name

```
bootstrap-datepaginator:
    js:
    assets/global/plugins/.js: {}
  css:
    theme:
      assets/global/plugins/.css: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - THEME_NAME/LIBRARY_NAME
```